# Show certain number of post from tags

Tags: query, tags, array

Hi i am using the query below to display post from a certain tag term, but what I want it to show multiple post.

So far the query is displaying only 1

```
<?php
$args = array('tag_slug__and' => array('morning-meat'), 'showposts' => array ('3'),);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<ul>
    <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Your issue is that it is only returning 1 post instead of 3? Are you sure there are 3 posts with that tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `showposts` as been depreciated in favor of `posts_per_page`

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tag_slug__and' => array('morning-meat')
);
```